# How to implement custom font to Android home screen widget after June/July security update?

Tags: android, widget, homescreen, font-family

After the last June (for Google Pixels) / June (for Samsung phones) the android:fontFamily attribute for the remoteViews doesn't work anymore. Google answer to my query is that it is intended behaviour for security reasons.

I've tried to use:

- downloaded fonts, both methods as a file and as an XML file with a link to Google Fonts,
- new class CustomTextView extends TextView and use it in an XML file,

BUT none of the methods works.

Can anyone enlight me on what method I need to use to be able to use a custom font in TextView in Android home screen widgets, please?

Regards
Adam

Comment: "Can anyone enlight me on what method I need to use to be able to use a custom font in TextView in Android home screen widgets" -- probably none. I am surprised that it worked in the first place. You could render the text using a `Canvas` to a `Bitmap` and display that, I suppose.

Comment: If Google themselves have said that it's intended behaviour that they're not supported, I think that's enough to confirm that it's not supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare for over a few years you could use the android:fontFamily attribute to set the custom font in XML layout files for any Android Home widget. Now it's gone hence my question. But thanks for the advice I will surely try Canvas to a Bitmap solution.

Comment: @HenryTwist, as I stated in the answer to CommonsWare the feature was present in the official documentation as an attribute you could use in XML layout files. I just cannot understand how the feature which points to the font file placed by the developer in apk can be hazardous for the user. Every apk is checked by Google before you can publish it, so for me, it is a bit puzzling especially that Google is very reluctant in giving any answers.

Comment: @CommonsWare so TextClock Widget is useless for showing time with custom fonts in home widgets ?

Comment: @Nils: In addition to the custom fonts issue discussed here, I do not see `TextClock` in [the roster of available UI widgets for use in app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#CreatingLayout). That being said, that may be a documentation bug -- I see `@RemoteView` on in the source for `TextClock` going back to [at least 7.0](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-cts-7.0_r33:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java), so perhaps that is usable.

Comment: @Nils: BTW and FWIW, [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190444596) contains more about the fonts-in-app-widgets discussion.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes TextClock usable in widget till now. And thank you.